# Error acessing mongo collection using mongo client asynchronously

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I've built the following mongo client access bootstrap file:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

let db = null;

// Connect to mongo
const uri = "mongodb://localhost/mydb";
const opts = { useUnifiedTopology: true };

const connect = async () => {
    console.log("Connecting to database...");

    let client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, opts).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error connecting to database: " + err);
    });

    if (client) {
        console.log("Database connected.");
        db = client.db("mydb");
    }

    return client;
};

// Get database connection
const getDb = async () => {
    if (!db) await connect();

    return db;
};

// Get Collection
const getCollection = async name => {
    let database = await getDb();

    let collection = await database.collection(name);

    if (!collection)
        throw new Error("(mongo) Cannot get collection named " + name);

    return collection;
};

export { db, getCollection };
```

When trying to acess the collection for the first time in another program:

```
import { getCollection } from "./mongoutils";

const init = async () => {
    let user = await getCollection("users").findOne({ name: "Josh"});

    console.log("User found!");
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (0 , _mongo.getCollection)(...).findOne is not a function
```

How can I properly fix this error, keeping the whole structure `async/await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An async function returns a promise and not the resolved data.

Here `getCollection()` is an async function. So, calling `getCollection("users")` would return a promise and not the resolved collection itself as I presume what you are expecting. The correct way to do is:

```
import { getCollection } from "./mongoutils";

const init = async () => {
    let userCollection = await getCollection("users");
    try {
      let user = await userCollection.findOne({ name: "Josh"})
      console.log("User found!");
    } catch (e) { 
      console.log("User not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make `getCollection` return the resolved collection, as this is what I need to later do collection queries asynchronously?

Comment: I'm not sure how the npm module `mongodb` api's work but you can try doing something like I did in the updated answer. :)

Comment: Your solutions does not solve my problem. I need it to work asynchronously as I have tons of collection calls and all of then as await/async. I really need an async solution...

Comment: Just like in case of your `getCollection()` function definition, you can not write something like `let collection = await getDb().collection(name)`, similarly you can not write `let user = await getCollection("users").findOne({ name: "Josh"})`. If you are hoping to run `getCollection("users")` and the `findOne()` operation in async then I believe there is no possible solution as findOne() can be run only and only after you have the user collection object with you. But still, good luck with your hunt. :)

Comment: How about: `let db = await getDb(); let collection = await db.collection(name); let  data = await collection.findOne(...)`` ?  Three waits, one for each async operation... Why that would not work?

Comment: Well, that is what I did in my answer if you look carefully. :)

Comment: You've changed your answer... But what is that different from what I did? What is the error in my code?

Comment: `let user = await getCollection("users").findOne({ name: "Josh"});` this line is throwing error in your code I believe.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I need 2 operations instead of 1... Easy... Thanks!